# Unable to get Maven version from /usr/share/Maven/bin/MVN Could not find system variable

Tags: docker, bamboo

I want to run bamboo remote agent using docker.
When I run the image atlassian/bamboo-java-agent in my machine it produces the following error

1. Unable to get Maven version from /usr/share/maven/bin/mvn Could not find system variable
2. If you wish to use perforce please set the location as a capability.

How to solve these two errors?

I later updated my Maven to higher version 3.3, but that is not reflected when I run the image as shown in the pic attached.

[image]